# What are test "descendants" in nunit 3?

Tags: c#, nunit

After reading [the NUnit 3 documentation regarding test parallelization](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/technical-notes/usage/Framework-Parallel-Test-Execution.html), I'll admit I'm confused on what a "descendant" is with regards to how the tests are run in parallel. In my mind, there are cases where I want all methods marked with `[Test]` to run in parallel to each other, as well as in parallel to other ones in different test fixture classes. For example:

```cs
[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]
class FixtureA
{
    [Test] public void TestCaseA_One() {}
    [Test] public void TestCaseA_Two() {}
}

[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]
class FixtureB
{
    [Test] public void TestCaseB_One() {}
    [Test] public void TestCaseB_Two() {}
}
```

My expectation above is that all 4 test case methods run parallel without regard to each other. Without a clear understanding of what a "descendant" is (and quite frankly, how nunit structures the tests, which may be required to understand this), I'm not sure what to expect. So my questions are:

1. Is `ParallelScope.All` necessary here to get the effect I'm looking for? Or is it simply enough to use `[Parallelizable]`?
2. What is a "descendant" given the example above? I assume that the test fixture *itself* has no material purpose; and that this ultimately boils down to is a flat list of methods that gets executed.
3. Descendant implies a hierarchy; what would a nunit test hierarchy look like? I can see how classes can build a hierarchy of tests (inheritance, but why would you?), but how do methods become "descendants"? Overall, just confused on test structure I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: it has nothing to do with the use of inheritance in your tests. :-)

Longer:

NUnit is an xunit-style framework, like SUnit, JUnit,xUnit.net, MbUnit, etc.

The fundamental design pattern of xunit is the well-known Composite pattern. That is, a "test" is either an individual test case **or** an composite of multiple tests. So, if we take the following code...

```cs
namespace My.Tests
{
    public class SomeFixture
    {
        [Test]
        public void SimpleTest() { }

        [TestCase(1, 2, 3)]
        [TestCase(4, 5, 6)]
        [TestCase(7, 8, 9)]
        public void ParameterizedTest(int x, int y, int z);
    }
}
```

... each of the following is a "test" in NUnit...

1. My
2. My.Tests
3. My.Tests.SomeFixture
4. My.Tests.SomeFixture.SimpleTest
5. My.Tests.SomeFixture.ParameterizedTest
6. My.Tests.SomeFixture.ParameterizedTest(1,2,3)
7. My.Tests.SomeFixture.ParameterizedTest(4,5,6)
8. My.Tests.SomeFixture.ParameterizedTest(7,8,9)

Items 1, 2, 3 and 5 have descendants. Items 4, 6, 7 and 8 do not.

For example, ParameterizedTest(1,2,3) is a descendant of ParameterizedTest,
which is a descendant of SomeFixture, which is a descendant of My.Tests,
which is a descendant of My. In addition, the assembly itself is a test
and everything I listed descends from the assembly.

It's fairly common to talk about these as "descendants" even though it's easy
to get confused with the O-O use of the term. In fact, the term comes from the
fact that inheritance is used **internally** to implement the pattern. But that's invisible to the user and it may be more useful to think about "contained tests" rather than "dependant tests".

Note however that the higher level tests really do "depend" on the lower level tests in the sense that the higher level can't pass unless the lower levels pass.

UPDATE -

`[Parallelizable]` is equivalent to `[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Self)]`

As your code is written, the two fixtures may run in parallel with one another **and** the member tests may also run in parallel.

If you change the attribute to `[Parallelizable]`, then the fixtures would run in parallel while the member tests within each fixture ran sequentially.

Comment: Great answer. Could you comment on the behavior of the example I provided? What happens if I remove `ParallelScope.All`?